# Targeted Device Family Specifies

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipados

Does Targeted Device Family -> `iPhone` prevent iPad users from seeing/downloading my published app? Or is it only for formatting purposes?

Context: iPad simulator looks terrible when I set Targeted Device Family to `iPhone`, so if iPad usage is inevitable, I'll set it to both, otherwise I would prefer for the app to be iPhone only.

Comment: You cannot prevent an iPad user from seeing/downloading it, even if it's set to `iPhone`

Comment: @jnpdx That answers my question, thanks! Feel free to post that as an answer, and I'll mark yours as preferred.